# Why is my Swagger index.html page blank after publication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I am writing an ASP.NET Core web API. My environment is ASP.NET Core 5.0, using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 19 in development, Windows Server 2016 and IIS in production. I'm developing in C# and implementing Swagger via Swashbuckle. This is my first ASP.NET Core app, so I'm very much a novice.

Here's the thing - when I run the project from Visual Studio 19, the Swagger page shows up just as I expect. I publish the project to a folder and copy that folder out to the destination, which is configured in IIS on local port 35701. When I navigate to http://localhost:35701/swagger/index.html I do get a page titled "Swagger UI", the page is otherwise blank. I get the same thing if I run the .NET Core app outside of IIS and navigate to http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html. I also get the same behavior if I publish in Debug or Release mode.

I figure it has to be something in my configuration, but I can't figure out what.

Here's my Startup class:

```
    public class Startup
        {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
            Configuration = configuration;
            }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "XoikosOnlineOrderingAPI", Version = "v1" });
                string filePath = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "XoikosOnlineOrderingAPI.xml");
                c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
                });
            }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "XoikosOnlineOrderingAPI v1"));

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
            }
        }
```

Here's my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51728",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "XoikosOnlineOrderingAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the source code to the Swagger UI page I'm getting:

```
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <style>

        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: #fafafa;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <!-- Workaround for https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1371 -->
    <script>
        if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
            console.log("Removing native Edge fetch in favor of swagger-ui's polyfill")
            window.fetch = undefined;
        }
    </script>

    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* Source: https://gist.github.com/lamberta/3768814
         * Parse a string function definition and return a function object. Does not use eval.
         * @param {string} str
         * @return {function}
         *
         * Example:
         *  var f = function (x, y) { return x * y; };
         *  var g = parseFunction(f.toString());
         *  g(33, 3); //=> 99
         */
        function parseFunction(str) {
            if (!str) return void (0);

            var fn_body_idx = str.indexOf('{'),
                fn_body = str.substring(fn_body_idx + 1, str.lastIndexOf('}')),
                fn_declare = str.substring(0, fn_body_idx),
                fn_params = fn_declare.substring(fn_declare.indexOf('(') + 1, fn_declare.lastIndexOf(')')),
                args = fn_params.split(',');

            args.push(fn_body);

            function Fn() {
                return Function.apply(this, args);
            }
            Fn.prototype = Function.prototype;

            return new Fn();
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            var configObject = JSON.parse('{"urls":[{"url":"/swagger/v1/swagger.json","name":"XoikosOnlineOrderingAPI v1"}],"deepLinking":false,"persistAuthorization":false,"displayOperationId":false,"defaultModelsExpandDepth":1,"defaultModelExpandDepth":1,"defaultModelRendering":"example","displayRequestDuration":false,"docExpansion":"list","showExtensions":false,"showCommonExtensions":false,"supportedSubmitMethods":["get","put","post","delete","options","head","patch","trace"],"tryItOutEnabled":false}');
            var oauthConfigObject = JSON.parse('{"scopeSeparator":" ","scopes":[],"useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant":false,"usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant":false}');

            // Workaround for https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5945
            configObject.urls.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.url.startsWith("http") || item.url.startsWith("/")) return;
                item.url = window.location.href.replace("index.html", item.url).split('#')[0];
            });

            // If validatorUrl is not explicitly provided, disable the feature by setting to null
            if (!configObject.hasOwnProperty("validatorUrl"))
                configObject.validatorUrl = null

            // If oauth2RedirectUrl isn't specified, use the built-in default
            if (!configObject.hasOwnProperty("oauth2RedirectUrl"))
                configObject.oauth2RedirectUrl = (new URL("oauth2-redirect.html", window.location.href)).href;

            // Apply mandatory parameters
            configObject.dom_id = "#swagger-ui";
            configObject.presets = [SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis, SwaggerUIStandalonePreset];
            configObject.layout = "StandaloneLayout";

            // Parse and add interceptor functions
            var interceptors = JSON.parse('{"RequestInterceptorFunction":null,"ResponseInterceptorFunction":null}');
            if (interceptors.RequestInterceptorFunction)
                configObject.requestInterceptor = parseFunction(interceptors.RequestInterceptorFunction);
            if (interceptors.ResponseInterceptorFunction)
                configObject.responseInterceptor = parseFunction(interceptors.ResponseInterceptorFunction);

            // Begin Swagger UI call region

            const ui = SwaggerUIBundle(configObject);

            ui.initOAuth(oauthConfigObject);

            // End Swagger UI call region

            window.ui = ui
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what other details I can add. Please ask for anything that might shed some light on what's going on. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So your swagger page can work only under IIS Express, is it correct? Could you look for errors in a browser console? Also, it can be useful to open `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` directly in a browser tab and see if there are any errors

Answer (score 1):

I spent several days troubleshooting. it turned out if I publish in x86, it's no longer a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before when the XML file for Swagger isn't published to the server. The one from this line.

```
c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
```

In Visual Studio there is an option when you right click on the XML file for "Copy to Output Directory" - ensure thats set to "Copy Always"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I had the same issue and spent about half a day on it. I am working with .net 8.
It turned out that the following method caused the issue:

```
    [HttpGet( "{*url}", Order = 999 )]
    [ApiExplorerSettings( IgnoreApi = true )]
    public IActionResult CatchAllOtherEndpoints()
    {
        // ...
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Adding the following regex in the route to exclude 'swagger' solved the problem:

```
    [HttpGet( "{*url:regex(^(?!swagger$).*$)}", Order = 999 )]
```

Credits go to this github post which let me to the root of the problem: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2616#issuecomment-1555948309